# Windows 7 Explorer crashes when selecting/moving multiple files

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, freeze

I have tried all the solutions suggested in this thread. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-explorer-freezes-when-moving-files-or/b576f33d-ed81-402e-8af9-b59b8ca90c0b

I can move single files.

I've had problems selecting a block of files with <kbd>right-click</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>.

In Folder Options/View I reset the "folder views" and I can now select multiple files but only a very few.  If a larger number (20 files) if freezes.  Even when I can select multiple files, Explorer freezes if I try to move more than one file with drag and drop.

This first occurred when I was consolidating folders and moved large numbers of files at one go, moving between two open Explorer windows.

I have the same problem even in Safe Mode.

I've run /scannow and I've run the "Repair Windows" program in Safe Mode startup.
If I tried to move a folder, it says it can't move the folder because a file in it is open in another program.  No other programs are running when this happens.

All other programs seem to be working fine.  It is just Explorer.

Comment: capture a crash dump of the Explorer: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU zip and share the dmp, I'll analyze it.